# xubuntu 14.04 VPN connection has no network access

Tags: networking, xubuntu, vpn

I am using the 'Network Connections' app under 'All Settings' to configure and connect to a VPN server for the purposes of accessing network resources and using Remote Desktop with Reminna. The VPN establishes a connection but I am unable to access any network resources.

For some background, I have successfully done this in past weeks with my current setup, the only change is that I have moved and received a new cable modem (gateway device). I have made sure this new device has no firewall setting and that Port Forwarding for 3389(RPD) is configured. I also noticed that the local networks (home & work) were configured to 10.0.0.x, so I reconfigured my local to be 10.0.1.x so there would be less confusion. Also while I am troubleshooting and need internet access, under IPv4 Settings->Routes I have marked the box for 'Use this connection only for resources on its network'.

Furthermore I have been able to connect to my VPN and successfully remote into computers and resources with my Android tablet and my Win7 computer which are on the same network as my xubuntu 14.04 computer. This seems to suggest that my routes or vpn configuration may have problems. I have attempted deleting and re-creating my vpn configuration from scratch with no effect. I've done my best to search the web and find similar problems/solutions but I am stumped. For troubleshooting, I have provided both route and ifconfig results from before and after the vpn connection and also added the /var/log/syslog output.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Non-vpn connected route command

```
:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask         Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
default         10.0.1.1    0.0.0.0         UG      0       0   0   eth0
10.0.1.0        *           255.255.255.0   U       1       0   0   eth0
```

With VPN "connection successfully established"

```
:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask         Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
default         10.0.1.1    0.0.0.0         UG      0       0   0   eth0
10.0.0.90       *           255.255.255.255 UH      0       0   0   ppp0
10.0.1.0        *           255.255.255.0   U       1       0   0   eth0
xx-xx-xx-xx-st  10.0.1.1    255.255.255.255 UGH     0       0   0   eth0
xx-xx-xx-xx-st  10.0.1.1    255.255.255.255 UGH     0       0   0   eth0
```

ifconfig results without vpn

```
:~$ ifconfig
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:16:7e:63:62:10  
        inet addr:10.0.1.30  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: <xx>:acff/64 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>:6210/64 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>::ca4e/128 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>:6210/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:608006 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:401539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:586253471 (586.2 MB)  TX bytes:39736340 (39.7 MB)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:44231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:44231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:3993104 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3993104 (3.9 MB)
```

With VPN connected

```
:~$ ifconfig
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:16:7f:01:62:10  
        inet addr:10.0.1.30  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: <xx>acff/64 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>:6210/64 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>::ca4e/128 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: <xx>:6210/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:607270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:400937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:586134269 (586.1 MB)  TX bytes:39688705 (39.6 MB)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:44145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:44145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:3985819 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3985819 (3.9 MB)

ppp0    Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
        inet addr:10.0.0.95  P-t-P:10.0.0.90  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
        RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
        RX bytes:1045 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 B)
```

My var/log/syslog file yields the following output after I initiate the vpn connection.

```
Jul 19 16:26:15 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Jul 19 16:26:15 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 16132
Jul 19 16:26:15 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN connection 'SLGI-1' (Connect) reply received.
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pppd[16136]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pppd[16136]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pppd[16136]: Using interface ppp0
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pppd[16136]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pptp[16139]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone NetworkManager[704]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone NetworkManager[704]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jul 19 16:26:21 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 33436).
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:950]: PPTP_SET_LINK_INFO received from peer_callid 58759
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:953]:   send_accm is 00000000, recv_accm is FFFFFFFF
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pptp[16155]: nm-pptp-service-16132 warn[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:956]: Non-zero Async Control Character Maps are not supported!
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pppd[16136]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 19 16:26:22 silentone pppd[16136]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone pppd[16136]: local  IP address 10.0.0.96
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone pppd[16136]: remote IP address 10.0.0.90
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone pppd[16136]: primary   DNS address 10.0.0.8
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone pppd[16136]: secondary DNS address 10.0.0.9
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN connection 'vpn1' (IP4 Config Get) reply received from old-style plugin.
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN Gateway: xx.xx.xx.xx
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> Tunnel Device: ppp0
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> IPv4 configuration:
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Internal Address: 10.0.0.96
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Internal Prefix: 32
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.0.0.90
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Forbid Default Route: yes
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Internal DNS: 10.0.0.8
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   Internal DNS: 10.0.0.9
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info>   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Jul 19 16:26:24 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> No IPv6 configuration
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN connection 'vpn1' (IP Config Get) complete.
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> Policy set 'LAN on Realtek[Asus]' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> Policy set 'LAN on Realtek[Asus]' (eth0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS.
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: using nameserver 10.0.0.9#53 for domain 10.in-addr.arpa
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: using nameserver 10.0.0.8#53 for domain 10.in-addr.arpa
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: using nameserver 2001:558:feed::2#53
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: using nameserver 75.75.75.75#53
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dnsmasq[1560]: using nameserver 75.75.76.76#53
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone NetworkManager[704]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dbus[612]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Jul 19 16:26:25 silentone dbus[612]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on outputs you don't have any `route` to any `network` witch is routed through `vpn connection`. Try to add route of remote vpn side to go on `ppp0` interface.
For resources on `vpn` side tou must have route. Something like

```
:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask         Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
default         10.0.1.1    0.0.0.0         UG      0       0   0   eth0
10.0.0.90       *           255.255.255.255 UH      0       0   0   ppp0
**10.0.0.0        *           255.255.255.0   U       1       0   0   ppp0**
10.0.1.0        *           255.255.255.0   U       1       0   0   eth0
xx-xx-xx-xx-st  10.0.1.1    255.255.255.255 UGH     0       0   0   eth0
xx-xx-xx-xx-st  10.0.1.1    255.255.255.255 UGH     0       0   0   eth0
```

Route can add on several ways:

tell vpn server to push route to client

```
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

or simple add manual route when ppp0 is connected

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.90 dev ppp0
```

or add route in `Network Connections` app under `All Settings`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Many thanks! I configured the VPN route as described and was able to access network resources.